# VB 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to insert data into a table in MySql. Here is the code that I have.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
        Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection()
        Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=test;database=YHI"

        Try
            Mysqlconn.Open()
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Main(Character,Import_Date) VALUES(@character, @import_date)")
            COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@character", Character)
            COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@import_date", ImportDate)
            COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Ore counts for " & Character.Text & " imported successfully")

        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)
        Finally
            Mysqlconn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Here is the error message I receive:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Connection must be valid and open.

I'm new to programming in VB, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not connecting your `Mysqlconn` to your `COMMAND` (at least I don't think so - can't see where you declare `COMMAND`).

There are a few ways to achieve this, but the simplest with your existing code would be just to set it as follows:

```
Mysqlconn.Open()
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Main(Character,Import_Date) VALUES(@character, @import_date)")
COMMAND.Connection = Mysqlconn
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@character", Character)
```

Comment: It is declared at the top. Adding the Connection line now is causing the following issue
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the maual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Character,Import_Date) VALUES(_binary 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 'test,'2 at line one. Any Ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're setting the values of `Character` and `Import_Date` wrongly - Hard to tell but would guess that you're using `TextBox.ToString` instead of `TextBox.Text` maybe?

Comment: Edit: It didnt work after all. I'm still receiving the incorrect syntax at line 1 error Here is my Dim code:
    Dim Mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim ImportDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the connection.

```
COMMAND.Connection = MySqlconn
```